# Как в PyQt5 QtMultimedia воспроизвести видео файлы в плейлисте случайным образом или с очередностью

Tags: pyqt5

Данный участок кода в бесконечном цикле проигрывает один и тот же файл в папке. Хотя по задумке должен проигрывать все, что лежит в папке в бесконечном цикле. Как правильно сделать это?

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import glob
import random
import os


class New(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("video_form.ui", self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()


    def my_video(self):
        list = [1, 2]
        video_path = 'D:/путь к папке с видео'

        mmm = random.choice(list)
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(video_path, f'{mmm}.mp4')):
            self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)))
            self.player.setVideoOutput(self.VIDEO_widget)
            self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(1)
            self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.CurrentItemInLoop)
            self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
            self.player.play()


    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.my_video()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***video_form.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);</string>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="modal">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_7">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>700</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0.492, y2:1, stop:0.0197044 rgba(0, 0, 93, 218), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));</string>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>ххх</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QVideoWidget" name="VIDEO_widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QVideoWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему

Comment: настораживает то, что вы где-то используете бесконечный цикл. Если вам действительно нужна помощь - предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class New(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("video_form.ui", self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()

    def my_video1(self):
         self.playlist.addMedia(
             QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('D:\\путь\\1.mp4')))
         self.playlist.addMedia(
             QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('D:\\путь\\2.mp4')))
         self.playlist.addMedia(
             QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('D:\\путь\\3.mp4')))

         self.player.setVideoOutput(self.VIDEO_widget)
         self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.Random)
         self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
         self.player.play()

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.my_video1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***video_form.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);</string>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="modal">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_7">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>700</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0.492, y2:1, stop:0.0197044 rgba(0, 0, 93, 218), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));</string>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>ххх</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QVideoWidget" name="VIDEO_widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QVideoWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Можно применить (QMediaPlaylist.Loop) и в бесконечном цикле проигрывать плейлист